# How to set the GCP Autoscaler to use "Time series per instance"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to set my Autoscaler to use "Time series per instance" rather than "Single time series per group", and I want to set it either via the gcloud tool or, ideally, via terraform.

I don't see either of these to be a setting that I can configure, and my autoscaler is set to "Single time series per group" by default with the following terraform config (I'm using version 3.62.0):

```
resource "google_compute_region_autoscaler" "engine_autoscaler" {

  name = "myautoscaler"
  project = "myproject"
  region = "europe-west1"
  target = google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.mymig.self_link
  autoscaling_policy {
    max_replicas = 10
    min_replicas = 1
    cooldown_period = 30
    metric {
      name = "custom.googleapis.com/mymetric"
      type = "GAUGE"
      target = 1
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried setting the Autoscaler according to the example in [Google's documentation about per-instance metrics](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#configure_per_instance):

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-autoscaling example-managed-instance-group \
--custom-metric-utilization metric=example.googleapis.com/path/to/metric,utilization-target-type=GAUGE,utilization-target=10 \
--max-num-replicas 20 \
--cool-down-period 90 \
--region us-west1
```

However, this also created an Autoscaler with "Single time series per group" settings, despite what is suggested in the documentation.

How can I change this setting? I can't do this through the browser because I need this to be automated via terraform/gcloud.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `custom-metric-utilization`, use [`stackdriver-metric-single-instance-assignment`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/set-autoscaling#--stackdriver-metric-single-instance-assignment). On the API it would be [`autoscalingPolicy.customMetricUtilizations[].singleInstanceAssignment`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/autoscalers#Autoscaler.FIELDS.inlinedField_16).

Comment: @Jofre but that setting is for 'per group' settings. Note that the documentation I linked to mentions that this should be set when using per-group metrics

Comment: Where do you see your autoscaler configured as "Single time series per group"? In the console? Or can you see this anywhere else?

Comment: @Jofre I see it when editing the MIG and checking the autoscaler settings. I don't know any other way of checking this.

Comment: This seems like it was an interface problem. The type of loadbalancer is determined with the monitored resource: if it is `gce_instance` the UI should say `Time series per instance`, while the monitored resource `instance_group` should show as `Single time series per group`. However, the UI does not seem to show this properly when editing an existing loadbalancer. Nevertheless, the behaviour should be correct, it's only a UI thing. This seems like a bug in the console.

Comment: @Jofre That is likely the case, however it is hard to verify which setting is then the effective one, as this doesn't seem to be displayed anywhere else.